# Is there a way to track java compilation time by class?

Tags: java, performance, compilation

I contribute to a project with multiple java gradle modules. Two of them were merged recently and that raised the compilation time significantly. I've read that using inferred generics and overloaded methods can increase the compilation time.

Is there any tool that assists in finding slow compile time classes in Java? Or a linter that points out potential speed pitfalls?

Comment: I would use an incremental build so that the compile time doesn't matter so much, i.e. only the classes changed get recompiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do the same thing and had to come up with my own way, which I describe below.

First, notice that when you compile a class using `javac` you can pass the `-verbose` flag so that the compiler logs everything that's going on (it sends output to stderr).

In Gradle you can pass that option to the compiler as follows:

```
compileJava {
    options.verbose = true
}
```

That looks like this for my hello world class (hiding a whole lot of non-relevant stuff):

```
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[/Users/renato/programming/experiments/java/Main.java]]
[parsing completed 21ms]
[loading /modules/jdk.jsobject/module-info.class]
[loading /modules/jdk.management/module-info.class]

...

[checking Main]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/Serializable.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/Class.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/System.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/Appendable.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/Closeable.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/io/Flushable.class]
[wrote Main.class]
[total 229ms]
```

As you can see, you could capture stderr and then time how long it takes between it says `parsing started ...Main.java` and `wrote Main.class`.

If you keep track of the message for each source file and the equivalent class file, you should be able to get accurate information about how long it took to compile each class.

Unfortunately, I don't think Gradle allows us to consume the output of the Java compiler, so we need to use something else to run Gradle for us and parse that output.

Here's an example that uses a Groovy script to do that (with minor edits should work for you even in Windows, or just using `javac` or `mvn` to compile):

```
def projectDir = new File(System.getProperty('user.home') + '/programming/experiments/gradle')
def javaSourcesRoot = new File(projectDir, 'src/main/java').absolutePath
def classFilesRoot = new File(projectDir, 'build/classes/java/main').absolutePath
def sourcesPrefix = "[parsing started SimpleFileObject[$javaSourcesRoot/"
def donePrefix = "[wrote $classFilesRoot/"

log "Starting Gradle"
def gradle = ['gradle', 'compileJava'].execute((List) null, projectDir)

def stdout = new StringBuilder()
def stderr = new StringBuilder()


gradle.consumeProcessOutput(stdout, stderr)

assert gradle.waitFor() == 0: "$stdout\n$stderr"

def classInfo = [:]

stderr.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.startsWith(sourcesPrefix)) {
        def className = (line - sourcesPrefix - '.java]]').replaceAll(File.separator, '.')
        log "Started compiling class $className"
        classInfo[className] = [startTime: System.currentTimeMillis()]
    }
    if (line.startsWith(donePrefix)) {
        def className = (line - donePrefix - '.class]').replaceAll('/', '.')
        log "Done compiling class $className"
        classInfo[className].endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}

def results = classInfo.collect { String className, Map info ->
    "${className.padRight(20)} ${info.endTime - info.startTime}"
}.join('\n')

log "Results:\n$results"

void log(msg) {
    println "${new Date()} - $msg"
}
```

Result for my small sample project:

```
Fri Jul 23 16:39:18 CEST 2021 - Starting Gradle
Fri Jul 23 16:39:20 CEST 2021 - Started compiling class other.JavaType
Fri Jul 23 16:39:20 CEST 2021 - Started compiling class my.Main
Fri Jul 23 16:39:20 CEST 2021 - Done compiling class other.JavaType
Fri Jul 23 16:39:20 CEST 2021 - Done compiling class my.Main
Fri Jul 23 16:39:20 CEST 2021 - Results:
other.JavaType       9
my.Main              4
```

Times are in milliseconds, so `my.Main`, a hello world class, took 9ms to compile... `other.JavaType` is an empty class, took 4ms.